# Search first word in a field using filterrific

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, filterrific

I am using filterrfic gem to search an organization in the database. The problem I am facing is when I am searching for an organization whose name starts with National then I get the list of all the organizations which have National in their name. All I want is that it should just search the first word of the name_of_organisation field.

organisation.rb

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where('name_of_organisation LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
        all
    end
end


filterrific(
available_filters: [
        :search_query           
 ]
)

 scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
    return nil  if query.blank?

    terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)

    terms = terms.map { |e|
        (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
    }

    num_or_conds = 1
     where(
        terms.map { |term|
            "(LOWER(organisations.name_of_organisation) LIKE ?) 
        }.join(' AND '),
        *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conds }.flatten
    )
}
```

Currently it displays all the Organisation as below:
National Social Service
Society for National Serivce

But What I want is that it should only search first word of the name_of_organisation field and display just
Nation Social Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
where('name_of_organisation LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

to:

```
where('name_of_organisation LIKE ?', "#{search}%")
```

Notice the removal of the first `%` in the search string. In this case, `%` represents [any sequence of 0 or more characters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html). By removing the first one, it should only search for strings that start with your provided search string.